# Getting value from react native modal dropdown

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog, dropdown

I have installed as a dependency react-native-modal-dropdown an get it to display correctly, my issue is that i cannot get the selected value chosen by the user i know its something simple and straight forward but my brain just dont want to work today.

here is a snippet of code i am using

```
<View style={[styles.action, { justifyContent: 'space-between', position: 'relative' }]}>
<Feather name="map-pin" color="#05375a" size={24} />
<ModalDropdown style={{ width: '85%', paddingVertical: 10, marginTop: -10 }}
textStyle={{ fontSize: 18 }}
dropdownStyle={{ width: '65%', }}
dropdownTextStyle={{ fontSize: 18 }}
options={depotOptions}
onChange={value => setDepot(value)}
/>
</View>
```

any help is gratefully appreciated

Comment: Hey puggsy. Please check onSelect function which is triggered when you select your option

Comment: Can you add the code from the ModalDropdown component

Answer (score 0):

went a different route, but thanks for the responses

Will accept this as the answer once im allowed as i have to wait 20 hours before i can